# How to allow all special characters in a Route (Symfony2)

Tags: php, regex, symfony, routes, url-routing

How to allow all special characters: a-z A-Z and ?.!:/_()'` in route path? I tried this but it's not working at all. Because I want to make a bug report Action that sends an email with the description of the current bug.

```
bugReport:
path:     /bugReport/{eStatusCode}/{eMessage}
defaults: { _controller: utilisateurBundle:ExceptionReport:bugReport }    
requirements:
    eMessage: .[a-zA-Z1-9\-_\/?;!"`'()`\|{}]+
options:
    expose: true
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you actually need `eMessage: "[a-zA-Z0-9_/?;!\"\`'()|{}-]+"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add quotes around your pattern.

```
bugReport:
    path:     /bugReport/{eStatusCode}/{eMessage}
    defaults: { _controller: utilisateurBundle:ExceptionReport:bugReport }    
    requirements:
        eMessage: ".[a-zA-Z1-9\-_\/?;!"`'()`\|{}]+"
    options:
        expose: true
```

Online demo of this regex: https://regex101.com/r/vK4rV7/1